# Is there a way to refuse an i.p. without acknowledging it

Tags: routing, firewall

Is it possible to completely disregard incoming connections from an i.p. address or does the networking hardware of switches, routers, etc. prevent this from being possible? How do I get my router to refuse to even acknowledge certain incoming i.p.s?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inbound ACL to drop the packet but the router will still have to process the incoming packet to match against the ACL. Otherwise, the packet will be dropped.

Comment: Darnit... I figured that was the case... if it's incoming, the router sees it regardless... even if its invisible to other devices and doesn't send a ping back...  There has to be something to do about this... like a blacklist on firmware separate from a whitelist on another piece of firmware? eh... This is why I was curious. If I've thought of this, someone else has definitely had to have put thought into it. I mean, if you run a server and get multiple incoming, is it so far-fetched to simply separate traffic unobtrusively? Somehow?

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of the catch22 most providers face with DDoS protection. You could put a box at the edge of your network to filter it out, but you'll still get saturation on the edge link. It's usually better to just pay the upstream provider for on-demand DDoS protection.